# Prove that there are at least two different 6 element subsets whose sum are equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

If set $A=\{x_1,x_2,...x_{12}\}$, all of which are positive integers, and $x_i \le 150$ and $1\le i\le 12$,

Prove that there are at least two different $6$ element subsets, $S(a)$ and $S(b)$, that the sum of the elements in $S(a)$ equals the sum of the elements in $S(b)$.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The tags you used correctly included the tag pigeonhole-principle.  Use it.  Answer the question of how many six-element subsets there are and compare that number to the number of possible sums there are.  What does the result of the comparison imply?

> As a very loose upperbound estimate on the number of possible sums... if you add six positive numbers all of which are less than or equal to $150$... what can you say about their sum?  As for counting the number of subsets possible, the term "binomial coefficient" is relevant here.

$~$

> $6\times 150 = ?~~~~~~~\binom{12}{6}=?$

---

"*When you do $6\times 150$, that is to find the total number of possible subsets, correct?*"

No.  The number of possible subsets has nothing to do with $150$.  Had we been talking about a set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{12}\}$ where each $x_i$ is between $1$ and $31$, the number of possible subsets is the same as in the original example.

We have a twelve element set and we want to ask how many subsets there are... That is **precisely** what the binomial coefficient is used for.  The number of $k$-element subsets from a set with $n$ elements is the **definition** of the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$.  So... we have a twelve element set and we ask how many six-element subsets there are?  There are $\binom{12}{6} = 924$ subsets.

Next... We are curious how many different sums of six elements might be possible.  As a very crude estimate, we can say "oh, well, the sum will be smallest when all numbers are as small as possible, so the smallest sum will be at least as large as $1$ (*we could have done better and noted that the elements must have been distinct, so the smallest possible sum would have been $1+2+3+4+5+6=21$, but it doesn't matter that we were relaxed here*) and the largest sum will be when all numbers are as large as possible, so the largest sum will be at most as large as $150+150+150+150+150+150$ (*again, we could have been stricter here and noted again that since the numbers should all have been different that the largest possible sum would have been $150+149+148+147+146+145$, but again it doesn't matter*)"

So, since every sum is somewhere between $1$ and $900$, it follows that there are at most $900$ distinct sums.  I must emphasize again that this is a *very* crude estimate.  A more elaborate argument might have gotten that total down much further, perhaps down to as low as $600$ or so possible different sums given a particular collection of numbers in the set, but again... it doesn't matter since we got the number below $924$.

---

Now......... If we have more pigeons than holes, and we put each pigeon into a hole, there must be at least one hole with more than one pigeon in it.

We have our $924$ different subsets... these will be our pigeons.  We will put them into our different holes which are our possible sums between $1$ and $900$ (*some of which can't even be used, which we don't care*), specifically following the pattern that we put our subset into the hole that corresponds to what the sum of that subset actually is...

We have more pigeons than holes... we have more subsets than possible sums... so there is at least one hole with more than one pigeon in it... so there is at least one subset sum with at least two subsets having that sum...

Comment: When you do 6 x 150, that is to find the total number of possible subsets, correct? So 924, which is total number of possible sums, is greater than 900, which is total number of possible subsets, therefore there must be at least two different subsets whose sum are equivalent? Sorry for re-edit, am in mobile and clicked enter accidentally. Thanks

Comment: @RobRorry do you know what a binomial coefficient is?  Do you know what a binomial coefficient is used for?  Do you know why I am asking this question to you right now?  If you don't know the answer to these questions, then that is where you need to go do right now before continuing.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful explanation. If I may I have just another question to clarify some point you made. When you say there are 900 distinct sums, since possible sums are 1 to 900, why is that exactly? For instance, the highest possible sum, if elements in set A are not distinct, would be 150×6, because there would be 6 150s in a subset. But for smallest, if not distinct, would be 1×6. Why in that case it starts at 1 and not 6, so the range of distinct sums would be 6-900, and so there would instead be 894 distinct sums?  Thanks again

Comment: And yes I am familiar with binomial coefficient however we did not use such notation, instead as c(n,k). Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @RobRorry I had emphasized several times that it was a very loose bound.  Yes, you could talk about sums being from $6$-$900$ or from $21$ to $879$, or as mentioned as well, you could come up with a clever argument as to why there would necessarily be many fewer than that.  All that I care about is that the number of possible sums must be strictly less than the number of possible subsets.  It does not matter *by how much*.